# How do I add a custom table to a form in another module in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal

I am trying to make a module to add a table to a form in another module.  I found I can add the new data in a module_form_alter hook but how to I get it to run through a theme hook?  The module I am trying to modify has a theme hook for the page I want to modify.  I don't want to change the original form I just want to add a table with new data below it.
Thanks

Comment: `hook_form_alter()` cannot be executed from a theme, but only from modules.

Answer (score 1):

Arrange your data into table headers and cell rows, and return the output with

```
return theme('table', $header, $rows, array('class' => 'ifyouwantaclassname'));
```

That will return data themed in a table. $rows are constructed by looping the dataset and adding an array item.

But you also need to change the structure of the form with a theme hook.

http://www.akchauhan.com/create-drupal-form-using-theme_table-like-module-list-form/

Has a pretty good write up on how to do it.

Comment: In what function do I put the returned theme since I am trying to add this to another modules form?  Thanks

Comment: To alter a form implemented from a module, you need to implement `hook_form_alter()`, or `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` in another module.
`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` is used when you know the ID of the form to alter.